# Use node to capture stdout of function call

Tags: node.js, function, stdout, capture

I have a function `myFunc` that writes to stdout when called. Is it possible in node.js to capture this output and store it in a variable, and make sure the output does not appear in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

If the output from the function call is done via `console.log()`, then you can temporarily replace `console.log()` with your own version that captures the output:

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log("this is some output", "to stdout");
}

console.data = "";

// replace console.log
console.logX = console.log;
console.log = function(...args) {
    console.data += args.join(" ") + "\n";
}

myFunc();

// restore console.log
console.log = console.logX;

// console.data contains the capture data

console.log("all done now");
```

If you want things other than strings (like objects) to output correctly, you will have to do more work in your own `console.log()` to properly display objects.  This version will work fine for things that are already strings or convert easily to strings (strings, numbers, boolean).

Comment: Won’t this interfere  with other parts of the code running in parallell?

Comment: @johann1301s - Your question doesn't show or discuss anything about asynchronous code in this function.  If you want to show actual, real code, not just pseudo-code, we could comment further on that.